# Фиксированное положение фигур - C#

Tags: c#, консоль, вычислительная-геометрия

Подскажите, как зафиксировать положение фигур(треугольник и квадрат перемещаются по консоли, когда их координаты совпадут, нужно зафиксировать их положение)?
Думаю, что подобным образом:

1-ая фигура

```
public void DrawRectangle()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
                Console.WriteLine("*");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y + size);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + size, y + i);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                int[,] array1 = new int[x, y];


            }
            }
```

2-ая фигура

```
public void DrawTriangle()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x1, y1 + i);
                Console.WriteLine("*");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 + i, y1 + size);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x1 + i, y1 + i);
                Console.WriteLine("*");
                int[,] array = new int[x1,y1];



            }
    }
```

И проверка на совпадение координат

```
 if(array == array1)
            {

                return; 
            }
```

Comment: Как понимать совпадут координаты треугольника и квадрата? в смысле они пересекутся в любом месте?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan, да

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете вместо `int[,]`, оперировать более высоко-уровневым представлением как `Point` из `System.Drawing`.

Соответственно если у вас есть заполненный массив `Point` вы можете проверить на пересечение так:

```
using System.Drawing; // Не забудьте

// Заполняете этот массив точками фигур. 
Point[] pointsRectangle = new Point[size];
Point[] pointsTrianglee = new Point[size];

// проверка
if (pointsRectangle.Intersect(pointsTrianglee).Any())
{
  // 
}
```

`Intersect` вернет Вам все точки координаты которых совпадают (Point переопределяем метод `Equals` - по этому точки сравниваются по координатам `X` и `Y` корректно). Ну и `Any` вернет `true` если есть хоть одна совпадающая точка.

Comment: А если попроще?

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva, а что Вам не понятно? что делают методы `Intersect` и `Any`? или как это сделать через циклы `for`? Вы можете привести свою логику фигур что бы можно было привести решение на Вашем примере, а то из того что сейчас в вопросе сложно дать четкий ответ.

Comment: Я вообще не знакома с этими методами, а по заданию нужно сделать через for

Comment: Треугольник движется  вправо при нажатии на правую стрелку и вверх/вниз при нажатии на соотв. клавиши, квадрат движется влево при нажатии  на левую стрелку, вверх/вниз

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva, Код который Вы привели это весь код что у Вас есть?

Comment: нет конечно, мне показалось, что этих фрагментов будет достаточно. Могу весь разместить

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva, в зависимости от того что именно Вам нужно? Вам нужно только определить момент пересечения точек 2D массива?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы ,когда фигуры пересекутся, они перестали двигаться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53814/discussion-between-anton-komyshan-and-julia-ponomareva).